# ¿como puedo abrir una base de datos SQlite desde flutter?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, flutter, sqlite, dart

lo que pasa es que debo abrir una base de datos en flutter, la base de datos no es de una API rest si no que es local, uso el paquete de sqflite pero no se si el archivo de database que me enviaron deberia estar en algun lugar en especifico de la aplicacion porque no me deja abrirlo en el lugar donde lo tengo 'descargas'

Comment: La verdad es que no termino de entender cuál es tu pregunta o cuál es tu problema. ¿Podrías ampliar un poco más de información?

Comment: Bienvenido, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta aportando más información.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, revisa la documentación del propio paquete. Estas preguntas suelen estar resueltas en el README junto con ejemplos de uso.

https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Si quieres mas información sobre como abrir una base de datos sqlite mira este enlace:

https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_db.md

Si tienes un problema mas especifico, edita la pregunta y muestra tu código para intentar ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

```
Directory directory = await 
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

String path = join(directory.path, "persona.db");
 
final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(path);
```

La base datos en este caso persona.db esta en una ubicación fisica de tu movil